# how to read values from jsonarray?

Tags: java, json

This is Json file.

```
{
  "paging": {
    "next_offset": 100,
    "total": 247,
    "limit": 100
  },
  "body_stats": [
    {
      "weight": 208.0,
      "id": "13500547638911",
      "date": "2012-10-     12T15:12:50Z",
      "user_id": "13499829320503",
      "bmr": 2723.328,
      "bmi": 28.2067901234568
    },
    {
      "resting_heart_rate": 65.0,
      "weight": 135.0,
      "id": "1b5kegg00     00js2p5pfmg000000",
      "date": "2013-04-     15T00:44:12Z",
      "user_id": "13589643116210",
      "girths": {
        "abdomen": 30.0,
        "waist": 30.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to read values from this json,

```
try{
       Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/jdemo.json"));
       JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; 
       JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("body_stats");
       Iterator<Object> iterator = companyList.iterator();
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println(iterator.next());
       } 
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": "13500547638911",
  "bmr": 2723.328,
  "weight": 208.0,
  "bmi": 28.2067901234568,
  "user_id": "13499829320503",
  "date": "2012-10-12T15:12:50Z"
},
{
  "id": "1b5kegg0000js2p5pfmg000000",
  "weight": 135.0,
  "girths": {
    "abdomen": 30.0,
    "waist": 30.0
  },
  "user_id": "13589643116210",
  "date": "2013-04-15T00:44:12Z",
  "resting_heart_rate": 65.0
}
```

But I want to read `"girths"{" ",""}` from this how can I read `girths{}` value?

Comment: I see that it is printing `girths` for the second record. Do you mean you want to forcefully insert an empty `girths` field for the first record also?

Comment: @HariShankar-----no actually i want to read this girths{"",""} from the second record and from where it comes next in file again.

Comment: You read the data in the array.  Now you need to access the data in the array elements, which are JSON "objects".  And "girths" is another "object" inside (some of) the objects in the array.  See json.org -- read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach.

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("D:/jdemo.json"));
JsonObject  jsonObject  = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray   jsonArray   = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("body_stats");

 for(JsonElement body_stats : jsonArray) {
     JsonElement girths = body_stats.getAsJsonObject().get("girths");
     if(griths !=null) {
          //The logic
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`"girths"` should be another `JSONObject`, so I guess

```
.getJSONObject(2).get("girths");
```

on your `JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
       Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/jdemo.json"));
       JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; 
       JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("body_stats");
       Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = companyList.iterator();
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              JSONObject  jsonObject = iterator.next();
              Object  object = jsonObject.get("girths");
              if(object != null){
                   JSONObject  girths = (JSONObject )object ;
                   System.out.println(girths);
              }
       } 
}
```